# bootstrap row with columns and tables same row height

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have x bootstrap rows with y bootstrap columns, with x and y depending on a database query.
Within the y columns the data is loaded in a html table.
Since the tables are editable i'm trying to bring the table row height to the height of the highest field within all the div.column in each div.row.

Here is the part of the page I want to format.
So I need to access each 'tr' of each html table within the div.column and div.row, check which one is the tallest tr and apply this height to the other tr in the same row and this for each div.row differently.

```
<div id="main" >
<?php

$a=0;
$result = $conn->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$task[$a] = ( $row['task'] );
$a++;
}

$b=0;
foreach ($task as $row){
?>  

<?php
$query1 = ("SELECT step FROM somewhere where id = '$id' AND task = '$task'");
$result1 = $conn->query($query1);
$c=0;   
while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
$step[$c] = ( $row1['step'] );
$c++;}    
           $d=0; 
 ?>
<div class="row">
        <div class="column" >
            <?php
                include'tabelle_index.php'; // first html table of a div.row with the legend
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php                    
        foreach ($step as $row){
    ?>
  
    <?php $st= $step[$b];?>
        <div class="column">
            <?php include'tabelle_data.php'; ?> // html tables with the data from database
        </div>
    <?php
    $d++;
}

  unset($step);
   unset ($c);
?>
</div>

<?php
 $b++;
}
?>
```

TSo far the best I have got is to bring all tr in a div.row to the highest tr value but i'd like to do so for each single row of the tables

```
$('.row').each(function(){  
      
            var highesttr = 0;
      
    
      $('tr', this).each(function(){
        
      
        if($(this).height() > highesttr) {
          highesttr = $(this).height(); 
        }
      
      });  
               $('tr', this).height(highesttr); 
              console.log(highesttr);      
    });
```

Preview:

[image: Here you can see the first and the second row how it looks without formatting.]

Comment: i think its not possible with dynamic height.

Comment: Hi Pri. You might want to take a look at the CSS property `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code works for me at the moment:

```
jQuery.fn.GetIndex = function() {
    return $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
}



$('.row').each(function(){  

    var rows = $('table tr', this);

    rows.each(function() {
     var i = $(this).GetIndex() + 1;
     var highesttr = 0;
         if(rows.filter(':nth-child(' + i + ')').height() > highesttr) {
          highesttr = $(this).height(); 
        }
    rows.filter(':nth-child(' + i + ')').height(highesttr);
    
   });

});
```